# Is there any fast way to solve a quadratic matrix equation in Mathematica approximately?

Tags: matrix, numerics, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

Let the square nonsingular matrix $M$ is a given convergent matrix. What are the best scalar values for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (in the real numbers domain), at which the following quadratic matrix equation *approximately* holds:

\begin{equation}
M^2+\alpha M+\beta I\approx0.
\end{equation}

In fact, I would like to find the scalar values as closely as possible for the following matrix $M$ (as an example)

```
Clear["Global`*"]
SeedRandom[12345]
n = 1000; Id = SparseArray[{i_, i_} -> 1., {n, n}, 0.];
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
X = 1/SingularValueList[A, 1][[1]]^2 ConjugateTranspose[A];
M = A.X;
```

Also I tried to use NMinimize or FindInstance, but I failed. Please note that a rapid approach is more better for me to find more accurate values for the scalar paramteres.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to minimize? The sum of squares of elements of `M^2+alpha*M+beta*I` (Frobenius norm)? Another norm?

Comment: The applied norm is optional (Frobenius or Infinity). Just finding some approximate valaues for the scalars in any fast way is needed.

Answer (score 8):

One method is to use Mathematica's [`PseudoInverse[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PseudoInverse.html) on the matrix equation that involves the eigenvalues of $M$. To arrive at this matrix equation, multiply each side of $M^2 + \alpha M + \beta I \approx 0$ by an eigenvector $v_1$ of $M$, to get

$$ (\lambda_1^2 + \alpha \lambda_1 + \beta) v_1 \approx 0 \implies  \lambda_1^2 + \alpha \lambda_1 + \beta\approx 0,$$ 
where $\lambda_1$ is the corresponding eigenvalue for $v_1$. Repeat this for all three eigenvectors (assuming that $M$ is semi-simple) to arrive at the following approximate matrix equation

$$\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1 & 1 \\ \lambda_2 & 1 \\ \lambda_3 & 1 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta\end{pmatrix}  \approx - \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1^2 \\ \lambda_2^2 \\ \lambda_3^2 \end{pmatrix}. $$
To solve this use in *Mathematica*

```
{α,β} = PseudoInverse[{{λ1,1},{λ2,1},{λ3,1}}].{λ1^2,λ2^2,λ3^2}
```

Then all you need are the eigenvalues of $M$, which you can get through

```
{λ1,λ2,λ3} = Eigenvalues[M]
```

For a very large matrix it maybe impractical to find all of $M$'s eigenvalues, in which case you can use the [Power Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_method) to obtain, for example, the three largest eigenvalues and then use the above method to find α and β. The more eigenvalues you use the better the approximation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If the OP doesn't have a version with `PseudoInverse`, then he's not using _Mathematica_ as it was there in v1. But, it was last modified in v5, so at a minimum he should use that version.

Comment: Running the above with `M = DiagonalMatrix[{1,2,3}]`, I get `{4, -(10/3)}`. But, plugging this into `M.M + α M + β IdentityMatrix[3]` gives `DiagonalMatrix[{5/3, 26/3, 53/3}]`. So, I don't think your method is effective. Although, no solution may exist for the matrix I chose. Anyway to address that?

Comment: Hi there, my result for this calculation gave `{{1/3, 0, 0}, {0, -(2/3), 0}, {0, 0, 1/3}}`, which is not entirely terrible. In any case, the bigger the spread of the eigenvalues, the worse the approximation. If M has rank 100 with "strongly" different eigenvalues, then game over, no good approximation exists. On the other hand if you use a rank 2 matrix, such as `M = Outer[Times, z, w]+Outer[Times, x, y]` , for any lists (vectors) `z`, `w`, `x` and `y` then the solution will be exact. @rcollyer, thanks for your comments, I've edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

By construction, `M` is real symmetric and almost certainly positive definite.
The eigenvalues of `M` are `e = (d/d[[1]])^2`, where `d` is the vector of singular values of `A`.
The eigenvalues of `C = M^2 + alpha M + beta` are `e^2 + alpha e + beta`.
The eigenvectors `M` and `C` are the same as the left singular vectors of `A`, say `V`.
The offdiagonals of `V'CV` are zero.
The sum of squares of the diagonals of `V'CV` = the sum of squares of all the elements of `C`.
But the diagonals of `V'CV` are just the eigenvalues of `C`, so we can simplify the problem:
minimize `Tr[(e^2 + alpha e + beta)^2]`.
You already know `e`, because you constructed it from `d`, so the solution is immediate:
`{alpha = Covariance[e,-e^2]/Variance[e], beta = Mean[-e^2] - alpha*Mean[e]}`.
That's the exact least-squares solution.

EDIT - It occurred to me that, although getting the singular values of a 1000 x 1000 matrix takes only a few seconds, if you have to do it many times (e.g., inside a loop) then the total time may be prohibitive, so further analysis may help.

Simulations suggest that if the elements of `A` are iid Uniform[-1,1] then the expected value of `e` is close to `Reverse[(#/2 + ArcSin[#]/Pi)^2 & [Range@n/n]]`.  This code

```
{n = #, y = -(x = (#/2 + ArcSin[#]/Pi)^2 & [Range@n/n])^2;
 N@{a = (n x.y - (Tr@x)(Tr@y))/(n x.x - (Tr@x)^2),
    b = (Tr@y - a*Tr@x)/n}}& /@ {10,100,1000}
```

gives `{alpha,beta}` pairs for `n = {10, 100, 1000}`.

```
{{10, {-0.939996, 0.104015}}
 {100, {-0.764133, 0.0667884}}
 {1000, {-0.743093, 0.0626846}}}
```

The pair for `n = 1000` should be a good approximation to the actual least-squares coefficients for a sample 1000 x 1000 matrix.

EDIT 2 - I get the same results when the elements of `A` are normal and logistic as when they're uniform. Has taking n = 1000 put us in asymptoticland? **Would someone please check these results?**

EDIT 3 - I think what we're seeing is a result of the [quarter-circle law](http://www.ims.nus.edu.sg/Programs/randommatrix/files/sverdu_p.pdf) that the asymptotic density of the singular values of an `n` x `n` matrix whose elements are iid zero-mean random variables with variance `1/n` converges to `Sqrt[4 - x^2]/Pi, 0 <= x <= 2`. The singular values we are dealing with have been normalized -- i.e., divided by the largest one -- so (rounding some statistical corners) their asymptotic density is approximately proportional to `Sqrt[1 - x^2], 0 <= x <= 1`, and their cumulative distribution is approximately `F[x] := 2(x Sqrt[1 - x^2] + ArcSin[x])/Pi`. The function I gave in my first edit, say `K[p] := p/2 + ArcSin[p]/Pi`, is an approximate inverse of `F[x]`. The actual inverse has no closed form and must be found numerically, say `X[p] := Block[{x},x/.FindRoot[F[x]==p,{x,K[p]}]]`. For `n = 1000`, the rms error in approximating the normalized singular values using `X[p]` is typically much smaller than the rms error using `K[p]`; e.g., .00095 vs .0091 .